# I want to make a an script that when you release the left button in the case object, the circle object draw himself at the position of the case

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGWil.png)

When I compile, It says that I didn't referenced the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make too much use of `global` variables, eventually that will overwhelm your sight in the code. Try finding a solution with local variables as much as possible, that would keep things organised on the long run.

Personally, I would delete the current Draw Event in `obj_circle` and replace the current code in the Left Released Event with this:

```
instance_create_layer(obj_circle, x, y, "[Layer]"); //replace [Layer] with the layer where you want the obj_circle to be drawn.
```

This will let you create an obj_circle everytime a mouseclick is released, assuming it is desired to create multiple circles later on.